# sum 3dimensional matrix - Matlab Brute force

Tags: matlab, optimization, for-loop, brute-force

Hi I have the 3 dimensional matrix in the code below. I am trying to sum all the 24 elements of "n" for every "number_panels" and "number_turbines" combination.

what I have below doesn't sum across the 3rd dimension

for number_panels = 0:5

```
for number_turbines = 0:2

    for n = 1:24 % number of hours per day



hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n) = Demand(n) -...     
(PV_supply(n)*number_panels) - (WT_supply(n)*number_turbines);

if hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n)< 0

            hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n) = 0;

        end
daily_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1) = sum(sum(sum(hourly_deficit(:,:,:)))) 



        hourly_total_RES(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n) = PV_supply(n)*number_panels + WT_supply(n)*number_turbines;


        if hourly_total_RES(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n) < Demand(n),

            renewables_penetration(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n) = (hourly_total_RES(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n)) / Demand(n); % ratio of renewable energy supply to demand

        else
            renewables_penetration(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n) = 1 ;

        end
             peak_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1,n) = max(hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1,n));
    end
```

Comment: are you trying to calculate just the sum of a 3D matrix?

Comment: well the way i have created it, I am trying to sum across the "n" dimension so Yes I am trying to sum the 3D matrix

Comment: I expected this to work but it doesn't:                                    daily_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1) = sum(hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1),3)

Comment: I am just getting your code, it looks the end for your for loops are not there. if you post your complete code I can help.

Comment: i have edited the code above in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB sum(X) adds all elements of matrix X in one dimension.
If you want to just calculate the sum for one specific dimension use:

```
 S1=sum(X,dimension);
```

where "dimension" is 1, or 2, or 3 for a 3D matrix.

If you want to compute over two dimensions then you can do:

```
 S2=sum(S1,dimension);
```

where dimension here is 1, or 2.

Based on your code I think this is what you should do if you want to do it in for loops:

```
for number_panels = 0:5
   for number_turbines = 0:2
      for n = 1:24 % number of hours per day
         hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n) =...
           Demand(n) - (PV_supply(n)*number_panels) - (WT_supply(n)*number_turbines);

         if hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n)< 0
           hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n) = 0;
      end
      daily_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1) = ...
        sum(hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1,:));
    end
 end
```

Look at the ":" that I added to:
    sum(hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1,:));

Comment: I still get the same answer which is incorrect with your suggestion.

Comment: what is your X? is it a 3D matrix?

Comment: looking at this:sum(hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1)), in the sum() there is only one element and sum does not do anything for you. Are you trying to do this: sum(sum(hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1: number_turbines + 1)))

Comment: daily_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1) = sum(sum(sum(hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1)))

Comment: So basically I am trying to sum every number_panel and number_turbine combination across the n dimensions. Therefore I should get a number_turbine x number_panel matrix with an element in each postion representing the sum of the 24 values

Comment: is hourly_deficit supposed to be a 3D matrix?

Comment: ok as I said do this: daily_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1) = sum(sum(sum(hourly_deficit(:,:,:)));