# matlab for loop in brute force

Tags: matlab, optimization, for-loop, indexing, brute-force

hi I am working with the brute force method that I have shown in the code below.

the size of PV_supply, WT_supply and Demand are all 48x1.

what I am tying to do is calculate the "hourly_deficit" equation for n = 1:24 and n = 25:48 separately so as to output 2 "sets" of "hourly_deficit"

My code is

```
for number_panels = 0:5
    for number_turbines = 0:3
      for n = 1:24:48 % number of hours per day

  hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, n) =...
 Demand(n) - (PV_supply(n)*number_panels) - (WT_supply(n)*number_turbines);

end 
 end 
  end
```

I was hoping on some help with how I should adapt the for loop so as to get the results as I am looking for. As it stands, the for n = 1:24:48 only actually goes up to n = 24

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [sum 3dimensional matrix - Matlab Brute force](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484039/sum-3dimensional-matrix-matlab-brute-force)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1:24:48` means "from 1 by increments of 24 until 48": The values therefore would be `1 25 49...` if you kept the series going.  Since `49` is outside the bounds you defined, it stops at `25`.

One solution for doing what you want would be the following:

```
for n = 1:24 % 1 by 1 to 24

    hourly_deficit_1(...,..., n)= Demand(n)-(PV_supply(n)... %# truncated
    n=n+24;
    hourly_deficit_2(...,..., n)= Demand(n)-(PV_supply(n)... %# truncated

end
```

To generalize for any number of days, add a 4th dimension to the matrix.  Third dimension would be hour (1:24), 4th would be day.

```
for h=1:24 %# hours
    for d = 1:num_days %# which day
        n = h + 24*(d-1);
        hourly_deficit_1(...,..., h, d)= Demand(n)-(PV_supply(n)... %# truncated
    end    
end
```

Comment: thanks that works - since I am trying to add another 8760 n's is there any way of doing this code to deal with this large data set?

Comment: since the hourly_deficit will go up to hourly_deficit_365?

Comment: Edited in response to comment.

Comment: nice thank you ! do you think it is easier to work with a 365x24 matrix rather than with a 8760x1 matrix (reshaped) or is it effectively the same?

Comment: Just to confirm - there is a for loop for an "n" number of hours 1:24 and "h" 1:24 as well?

Comment: No.  Loop for `h`(hours) and `d`(days). Calculate `n` inside the loop.